# How to split the page with images on the right and information to the left

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning, wrapfigure

I would like to do the following but more correctly:

[image]

I would like to have to have the images on the right and information on the left. I tried using `wrapfigure` package to do it but I don't think that is the best route to take. What do you recommend I do to achieve this?

EDIT:

How can I the following so the images are side by side and the text between "Area" and table the is minimized? Here is an image:

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why a `tabular` environment wouldn't work for you, with the text in the left-hand entry and the graphic in the right?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I thought of using the tabular environment also but I don't how to set it up because I am using two graphics and the `wrapfigure` environment. @CountZero, I am using minipage within the wrapfigure, so do you mean I should have two other minipages that contain the information on the left and pictures on the right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED ANSWER (Without `\tabular`)  With this approach, each subsection can be tailored for the particular material.  As such, the `\parbox` can be made narrower, to allow room for two figures and to force its vertical extent to increase.

Note: I left original answer below this edit, because it constitutes a different approach wherein images & tables are all allocated an equal horizontal space on the page):

```
\documentclass{article}
\parskip 1em\parindent 0ex
\begin{document}
\section{Geographic Information}
\textbf{Country Name:} The conventional long form ``The United States of
America'' and the conventional short form is ``U.S.'' or ``The U.S.'' or
``America'' or ``The States.''

Two other maps can be found in the appendix.

{\large\textbf{Area, Time Zone, Climate}}

\textbf{Area}

\parbox[b]{1.6in}{
  Area of the United Sates is 9,826,675~m$^2$.  The United States as a
  percentage of Canada: 0.984\%.  Ontario as a percentage of the United
  States: 0.10\%
}
\hfill\rule{1.5in}{1in}\hfill\rule{1.5in}{1in}\\

\textbf{Time Zone}

\parbox[b]{2.3in}{
  Due to the size of the U.S., numerous time zones will be discussed.
}
\hfill
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  America& Ottowa (12:00 PM)\\
  CT & 11:00 A.M.\\
  EST & 12:00 P.M.\\
  MST & 10:00 A.M.\\
  PST & 9:00 A.M.\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

ORIGINAL ANSWER (with `\tabular`):

Here's one possibility, using `tabular` that I mentioned in a comment above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
\section{Geographic Information}
\textbf{Country Name:} The conventional long form ``The United States of
America'' and the conventional short form is ``U.S.'' or ``The U.S.'' or
``America'' or ``The States.''

Two other maps can be found in the appendix.

{\noindent\large\textbf{Area, Time Zone, Climate}}

\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\hspace{0ex}}lr@{\hspace{0ex}}}
\multicolumn{2}{@{\hspace{0ex}}l}{\textbf{Area}}\\
\parbox[b]{2.6in}{
  Area of the United Sates is 9,826,675~m$^2$.  The United States as a
  percentage of Canada: 0.984\%.  Ontario as a percentage of the United
  States: 0.10\%
}
& \rule{1.5in}{1in}\\
%
&\\
\multicolumn{2}{@{\hspace{0ex}}l}{\textbf{Time Zone}}\\

\parbox[b]{2.6in}{
  Due to the size of the U.S., numerous time zones will be discussed.
}
& 
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  \footnotesize
  America& Ottowa (12:00 PM)\\
  CT & 11:00 A.M.\\
  EST & 12:00 P.M.\\
  MST & 10:00 A.M.\\
  PST & 9:00 A.M.\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this looks pretty amazing. Could please give some explanation to your code so if I need to modify it I can.

Comment: @gekkostate The tabular is invoked to set up two columns "lr" is left justified col1 and right justified col2. The `@{\hspace{0ex}}` says get rid of the intercolumn buffer space normally found here. In the left column, I placed a `\parbox` 2.6 inches wide, but you can change that based on your margins. In the right column (following the `&` field separator), I placed a `\rule` to simulate your graphic shrunk to an appropriate size) and also a nested `\tabular` (for the time-zone chart, expressed in rows, not columns). If your graphics are too big, it will run into the right margin, so watch it

Comment: I have updated the question. I was wondering how can I get the images side by side and also how I can minimize the white space between "Area" and the table.